# SQL: How To Use DateDiff + ORDER BY with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, datediff

Here is my existing SQL statement:

```
SELECT TOP 10 Users.FirstName + ' ' + Users.LastName AS Name,
              Feeds.LogType,
              Feeds.LogDesc,
              Feeds.Timestamp = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Feeds.Timestamp, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
FROM Feeds
INNER JOIN Users ON Feeds.UserID = Users.UserID
ORDER BY Feeds.Timestamp DESC
```

I am having errors on the 2nd line, `Incorrect syntax near '='.`

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT TOP 10 Users.FirstName + ' ' + Users.LastName AS NAME
    ,Feeds.LogType
    ,Feeds.LogDesc
    ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Feeds.TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
FROM Feeds
INNER JOIN Users ON Feeds.UserID = Users.UserID
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Feeds.TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Feeds.Timestamp = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Feeds.Timestamp, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) should be

```
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Feeds.Timestamp, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS Timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of = try alias name as,

```
SELECT TOP 10 Users.FirstName + ' ' + Users.LastName AS Name, Feeds.LogType,
    Feeds.LogDesc,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Feeds.Timestamp, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) [Timestamp]
FROM Feeds INNER JOIN Users ON Feeds.UserID = Users.UserID
ORDER BY Feeds.Timestamp DESC
```

Comment: When posting code, please use the `{}` button, and use the preview to make sure that what you're posting is readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use alias in the manner "alias = value", but you should not specify table name, so

```
Timestamp = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Feeds.Timestamp, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```